# html href not linking to correct location

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a menu which is in header.php which is called as an include on each page I load. What is happening, is if I click a link in the header which has an absolute path, when I go the link and load the header.php I try to call an `onclick()` which used `'#'` as a href, but for some reason inherits the link to the folder I am currently in. Let me show you with example.

Menu structure:

Requests

```
<ul>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="addbox();" class="BA">Add Box(es)</a></li>
      <li><a href="/domain/admin/requests/boxes/index.php">Administration</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Files

```
<ul>
     <li><a href="#" onclick="addfile();" class="BA">Add Fil(es)</a></li>
     <li><a href="/domain/admin/reports/boxin/index.php">Administration</a></li>
 </ul>
```

If I click the Add Box(es) link while in the file menu, instead of linking to `addbox();` which is in the request link it is showing the link as: `/domain/admin/reports/boxin/index.php#`. How do I correct this. many thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help buddy. Guess someone just had a bad day

Comment: Instead of looking at the question you researched how mnay posts I have made. Jeez

Comment: I phrased the question as best I could. Perhaps I shouldn't have put the html in code. Thanks

Comment: did what. Is my question still open? If not why not

Comment: I was just doing that when I got edit warning That someone else was editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use void(0) or javascript:; instead of #

Like this

`<a href="javascript:;" onclick="addbox();" class="BA">Add Box(es)</a>`

OR

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="addbox();" class="BA">Add Box(es)</a>`

Comment: Nothing happens at all when I click the link using either method. Thanks

Comment: You are not # tag in the URL. Right?

Change like this.

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript: addbox();" class="BA">Add Box(es)</a>`

Check your above hyperlink tags (a). All tags should be closed (</a>).

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all, I think you should phrase your question properly. I can not understand what are you trying to say here.

Anyways, I will try to give my two cents from what I could understand:

I think your javascript is not loading early enough. So when a person is clicking on a link with `#` he is getting redirected to the home page with a `#` appended to the url.

To solve this, You should add:

```
onclick="return false;"
```

to every link along with the function you want to call that has a `#` in it.

Also, try to load your javascript before the page loads by placing your script tag in the head section. This is not a neat way but will help you in this case. You can optimize your code later.

eg:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#" onclick="addfile(); return false;" class="BA">Add Fil(es)</a></li>
 <li><a href="/domain/admin/reports/boxin/index.php">Administration</a></li>
<ul>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I already tried thought of that and tried <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="addbox(); return false" class="BA">Add Box(es)</a></li> but still the same result.

Comment: All my scripts are in the head tag. Thanks